# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any> | PromiseLike<Promise<any>>

Tags: typescript, jestjs

So I have a function

```
export const retryNTimes =  async (retryFunction: Function) => {
    let retry = 0;
    while(retry < MAX_NUMBER_OF_RETRIES){
        try {
            await retryFunction()
            break
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Try ${retry}: ${err}`)
            retry += 1
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this code for its unit tests:

```
    test('retry function to try 2 times', async () => {
        const func = jest.fn()
                .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('error'))
                .mockResolvedValueOnce(void 0)
        await retryNTimes(func)
        expect(func).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    })
```

This test passes just fine. But when I build it, it gets an error

```
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any> | PromiseLike<Promise<any>>'
```

on line

```
.mockResolvedValueOnce(void 0 )
```

Im not to sure how to fix this as im not to sure what the promise type means. Anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know jest (and please add it as a tag), but this looks like errors I have with other test libraries when I don't (restore the mocked function)[https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore ] and somewhere out of the test the mock i used and fails

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Added it as a tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that error and the name `mockResolvedValueOnce`, it seems like it expects you to pass a (resolved) Promise. You're passing a regular value.

Wrapping your value in `Promise.resolve(...)` might help, but I suggest re-reading the documentation of your test framework.